# json encode con php

Tags: php, json

Tengo una consulta que me arroja esta informacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la idea es presentarlo en json para su consulta, pero solo logro algo asi

```
"mensaje": [
{
    "tipoId": "CC",
    "documento": "123123",
    "idActividad": "1",
    "actividad": "Solicitud semestral",
    "fechaSolicitud": "01/06/2020",
    "estadodatos": "0"
},
{
    "tipoId": "CC",
    "documento": "123123",
    "idActividad": "2",
    "actividad": "Solicitud adicional",
    "fechaSolicitud": "01/06/2020",
    "estadodatos": "0"
},
```

y necesito arupar los datos asi

```
"mensaje":[
{
 "tipoId":"CC",
 "documento":"123123",
 "actividades":[
    {
       "idActividad":"1",
       "actividad":"Solicitud semestral",
       "fechaSolicitud":"01/06/2020"
    },
    {
       "idActividad":"2",
       "actividad":"Solicitud adicional",
       "fechaSolicitud":"01/06/2020"
    }
 ],
 "estadoDatos":"0"
},
{
 "tipoId":"CC",
 "documento":"321321",
 "actividades":[
    {
       "idActividad":"1",
       "actividad":"Solicitud semestral",
       "fechaSolicitud":"01/06/2020"
    },
    {
       "idActividad":"2",
       "actividad":"Solicitud adicional",
       "fechaSolicitud":"01/06/2020"
    }
 ],
 "estadoDatos":"0"
}
]
}
```

he intentado colocarlos en arreglos, pero no lo he logrado y soy muy novato en json.
Agradezco cualquier idea

los datos los traigo en un array asi:

```
$datos[]=array("tipoId"=>odbc_result($rs,"pactid"),"documento"=>odbc_result($rs,"pacide"),"idActividad"=>odbc_result($rs,"codactividad"),
        "actividad"=>odbc_result($rs,"actividad"),"fechaSolicitud"=>odbc_result($rs,"fechaSolicitud"),"estadodatos"=>'0');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos a ver que podemos hacer aquí.

Tu código en general está bien. Pero lo que te falta es construir la estructura que deseas.

El documento final que presentas es una agrupación de actividades bajo las claves de `tipoId` y `documento`.

Podemos afrontar el problema de dos formas. La primera sería recorrer los resultados e ir generando un array donde la clave sea `$tipoId-$documento` y guardar una lista de actividades.
Una vez hecho esto recorreríamos otra vez la lista para darle el formato final.

La otra opción es hacerlo todo en un solo recorrido... y como hemos venido a jugar es la que usaremos.

Pero primero tenemos que explicar la base. Vamos a utilizar `array_reduce` como su nombre bien indica, esta función reduce un array (lista) de objetos a un objeto único.

El ejemplo mas claro sería:

```php
var_dump(array_reduce(array(1,2,3,4), function($acc, $item) { $acc += $item; return $acc; }, 0));

# int(10)
```

`array_reduce` recibe 3 parámetros:

- el array sobre el que queremos operar
- La función a aplicar
- Y el valor inicial

La función a aplicar recibe 2 variables, la primera es un acumulador y la segunda es un item del array.

Así que la función será llamada una vez con cada número en el ejemplo.
Y `$acc` la primera vez tendrá el valor inicial que le hemos asignado (0) y en las siguientes ejecuciones tendrá el valor que retornamos en la misma función

Así que esta será la lista de llamadas para el ejemplo:

- n1; $acc = 0; $item = 1
- n2; $acc = 1; $item = 2
- n3; $acc = 3; $item = 3
- n4; $acc = 6; $item = 4
- result: 10

Hay un detalle importante en `array_reduce` y es que nada nos obliga retornar el mismo objeto... bien podríamos concatenar los números para devolver el string `1234`.

Volviendo a nuestro problema, en mi caso asumo que los datos están ya en un array:

```php
$db_data = [
    array(
        "tipoId" => "CC",
        "documento" => "123123",
        "idActividad" => "1",
        "actividad" => "Solicitud semestral",
        "fechaSolicitud" => "01/06/2020",
        "estadodatos" => "0"
    ),
    array(
        "tipoId" => "CC",
        "documento" => "123123",
        "idActividad" => "2",
        "actividad" => "Solicitud adicional",
        "fechaSolicitud" => "01/06/2020",
        "estadodatos" => "0"
    ),
    array(
        "tipoId" => "CD",
        "documento" => "12",
        "idActividad" => "2",
        "actividad" => "Solicitud adicional",
        "fechaSolicitud" => "01/06/2020",
        "estadodatos" => "0"
    )
];
```

Pero en tu caso habrá que leerlos del result set como ya bien haces.

Vamos a empezar con la implementación mas simple que se nos pueda ocurrir:

```php
$grouped = array_reduce($db_data, function($acc, $item) {
    $acc[] = array(
        "tipoId" => $item["tipoId"],
        "documento" => $item["documento"],
        "actividades" => [
            array("idActividad" => $item["idActividad"])
        ]
    );

    return $acc;
}, array());
```

En este ejemplo hemos convertido los datos de la DB en una lista de registros dónde tenemos el `tipoId` y `documento` en la raíz y dentro una lista de `actividades`. Sin embargo, nos daremos cuenta enseguida de que tenemos varias entradas para el mismo par de `tipoId` y `documento`.

Nótese que en este caso concreto no estamos haciendo nada especial con `array_reduce` podríamos usar `array_map` y tendríamos el mismo resultado..

Ahora lo que necesitamos es comprobar si ya existe una entrada en `$acc` para el set de claves que tenemos y si existe le queremos añadir una entrada en `actividades` en caso de que no exista creamos un registro nuevo.

Para encontrar si ya existe un registro con nuestro set de claves podemos recorrer todo el `array` hasta encontrarlo. Pero como hoy es un día especial y no tengo claro de cuantos registros estamos hablando, vamos a optimizar la función para no tener que hacer búsquedas.

Así que cambiaremos nuestro objeto `$acc` pasando de un simple array a un objeto un poco mas complejo, la definición será: `array("result" => [], "seen" => array())`

En `result` tendremos el resultado final y `seen` es un array clave/valor donde la clave es nuestro set de claves y el valor es la posición donde se encuentra en `result`! quizá quede un poco mas claro con el código

```php
$grouped = array_reduce($db_data, function($acc, $item) {
    $key = $item["tipoId"] . "-" . $item["documento"];

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $acc["seen"])) {
        array_push($acc["result"], array(
            "tipoId" => $item["tipoId"],
            "documento" => $item["documento"],
            "actividades" => [
                array("idActividad" => $item["idActividad"])
            ])
        );

        $acc["seen"][$key] = count($acc["result"]) - 1;
    } else {
        array_push($acc["result"][$acc["seen"][$key]]["actividades"], array("idActividad" => $item["idActividad"]));
    }

    return $acc;

}, array("result" => [], "seen" => array()));
```

Cómo vemos el método a cambiado un poco. Lo primero es que generamos un `$key` con el par de claves.
Luego comprobamos en `$acc["seen"]` si es clave ya la hemos visto antes.
En caso de que sea nueva, creamos la entrada completa y añadimos la posición en la que se encuentra.
Si no es una nueva entrada lo único que queremos hacer es añadir la actividad. Y dado que en `seen` tenemos la posición del array lo podemos hacer fácilmente.

El resultado es

```php
array(2) {
  'result' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    array(3) {
      'tipoId' =>
      string(2) "CC"
      'documento' =>
      string(6) "123123"
      'actividades' =>
      array(2) {
        ...
      }
    }
    [1] =>
    array(3) {
      'tipoId' =>
      string(2) "CD"
      'documento' =>
      string(2) "12"
      'actividades' =>
      array(1) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  'seen' =>
  array(2) {
    'CC-123123' =>
    int(0)
    'CD-12' =>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la GRAN explicacion, muy detallada y no me fue dificil poder implementarla, de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: de nada. no estaba muy seguro si sería util porque quedó un poco tocho!